# What is the greatest number that can be represented using once each digit and no other symbol?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

My best guess is
$$\Large 3^{4^{5^{6^{7^{8^{9^{10^{2}}}}}}}}$$
I have been searching but never found anything related to my question.

Comment: you could change $10^2$ to $210$ and make this number bigger for sure.

Comment: Have you checked out whether $2^{3^{4^{5^{6^{7^{8^{9^{10}}}}}}}}$ makes a greater number?

Comment: Could be  $3^{{{{{{{{2}^{4}}^{5}}^{6}}^{7}}^{8}}^{9}}^{10}}}}}}}}} $, but not sure, my main reasoning is x^y > y^x for y>x >e

Comment: You could change $10^2$ not to $210$, but to $2^{10}$...

Comment: I wanted to post 3^4^5^6^7^8^9^2^10

Comment: x^y^N > y^x^N for y>x>1 and big enough N. Smaller number always goes to the base. Which brings us to what @MostafaAyaz said.

Comment: You can use the edit button under the question to update your answer and also learn how to typeset these power towers using mathjax.

Comment: Without parentheses, your notation is completely ambiguous because exponentiation isn't associative ! For example $(a^b)^c \ne a^{(b^c)}$ in general.

Comment: Tetration may give a larger number.

Take $$\Large^{^{^{^{^{^{^{^{10}9}8}7}6}5}4}3}2$$
for example.

Comment: @JeanMarie By convention $a^{b^c}$ means $a^{(b^c)}$ since $(a^b)^c$ does not need the nested exponential notation; it could be simplified to $a^{bc}$.

Comment: @user7777777 Nice! As much as I have been able to find out, one can go up to hexation without using Knuth's up-arrow notation, wich might give us a best guess for the solution...

Comment: *a better guess

Comment: https://math.osu.edu/sites/math.osu.edu/files/chun_tetration.pdf

Comment: @Misha Lavrov I agree for 3, but is the convention so clear when you have 4, 5, ... n stacked "factors" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I admit that it's a bit less clear just because it comes up less often. But I see silly numbers of stacked exponents in Ramsey theory on a semi-regular basis, and none of them have parentheses - they all assume that we compute the exponent from the top down.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov All right, top down evaluation makes sense.

Comment: First , we need to know precisely which operations are allowed. If hexation is allowed this gives already HUGE numbers and it will be difficult to compare them in size. Conway chains or Bowers arrays as well as busy beaver expressions are not allowed , so I do not think we can get over the hexation level.